# Protected routes for react with a express backend protected by passport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes, passport.js

I am a little confused and the more I read, the more confused I get...

So I have an JS Express Backend that is protected by a PassportJS local Strategy and uses express-session. How would I proceed within my React Set Up now? Can I just make a route on my server, that checks whether the User is logged in or not, and then depending on the response set a React State accordingly, which  allows access to protected routes?
I assume all redirecting (for example for unauthorised request to a route) then takes place in the react app and not from the server (for example res.redirect()?

I am very new to React and web development, so I am a little confused about security here, because I thought all React-Front-End JS is accessible to the client!

Answer (score 1):

I've got 2 github repositories that are related and can help you.

[Authentication with React.js with JWT](https://github.com/jochri3/authentification-reutilisable-reactjs)

[Authentication using passeport](https://github.com/jochri3/authentification-robuste-reutilisable-nodejs)

You'll juste translate README in English cuz ot's in French.

The front-end repository connects to the backend repo created with express.The code is really easy to understand.

I hope that i will help